# Chinese characters in summary that I cannot knit to pdf

Tags: r, latex, linear-regression

````
```
model2 = lm(1/glyhb~ gender + age + gender:age ,data = diabetes)
summary(model2)
```

Call:
lm(formula = 1/glyhb ~ gender + age + gender:age, data = diabetes)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.149383 -0.019681  0.002455  0.029739  0.163164 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       0.2498158  0.0120415  20.746  < 2e-16 ***
genderfemale      0.0123141  0.0151608   0.812    0.417    
age              -0.0011384  0.0002363  -4.817 2.09e-06 ***
genderfemale:age -0.0002195  0.0003030  -0.724    0.469    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04778 on 386 degrees of freedom
  (因为不存在，13个观察量被删除了)
Multiple R-squared:  0.164, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1575 
F-statistic: 25.24 on 3 and 386 DF,  p-value: 6.264e-15
````

Error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 因 (U+56E0)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Can anyone help me to change this line under residual standard error to English please....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I remember adding something in the title module works but I forgot what that is

Comment: I doubt this has anything that is specific to Rstudio. the knitr package is shared by all the forks of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

works!